# Repeated deserializing and serializing when calling API - is there a better way?

Tags: c#, ajax, serialization, asp.net-core

I am developing a website along with an API to serve it data and have noticed that my current process involves repeated serialization and  deserialization of the same data when an API call is made. I was wondering if there is a better way to go about things. Both the website and API are written in C# using ASP.Net Core 2.0.

*My current process is as follows:*

1) End user loads website page

2) AJAX call is made from client side JavaScript, calling a C# function in the website.

3) The C# website function calls the API (using a Swagger generated client).

4) The API serializes data and returns it to website as JSON.

5) The Swagger client in the web site deserializes the data back to a POCO class.

6) The Website C# function serializes the data back to JSON to return it to AJAX function.

7) Something is done with the JSON data in the client - inevitably after first parsing the JSON.

*Example Code:*

AJAX call:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', "/GetData", true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    doSomething(data);
    }.bind(this);
xhr.send();
```

Website method:

```
[Route("/GetData")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData()
{
    var data = await ApiClient.ApiDataGetAsync();
    return Json(data);
}
```

API Method:

```
[HttpGet]
public Dictionary<int, string> GetData()
{
    return _logic.GetData();
}
```

As the above shows the data is serialized to JSON by the API before being deserialized to a POCO by the Swagger client, then serialized back to JSON in the website to be processed client side.

I realize I could simplify this by calling the API directly from the AJAX rather than going through the website but I would rather avoid this for a number of reasons:

1) It would tightly couple the API to the front end of the website, at the moment I have the option of implementing an interface layer in the site to simplify things if the API needs to be replaced in the future.

2) It would reduce my control over who can access the API - at the moment it is locked down by IP address.

Is there a way I can improve this process so the data doesn't have to be serialized twice whilst retaining the Swagger client?

Comment: How would you make this shorter?

Comment: I don't know, I just wanted to find out if it was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What problem are you actually trying to solve?  The time taken to serialize/deserialize the json is tiny compared to the time taken for networked i/o.

At this point I would say you are trying to optimise something without knowing whether it will improve application performance or reduce cost, which is generally considered a waste of time.

Comment: You may be right, it just seemed like an odd aspect of what I thought was a common design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can forgo the client and simply make your action a proxy using `HttpClient` to fetch from the API.

The client is intended to actually give you C# objects to work with, so it serializes/deserializes the request/response to make it easier for you to work with the API. That's sort of the whole point. What you're saying is that you don't actually want this, so simply drop the client.

Instead, you can make the request directly to your API from the action, using `HttpClient`, and then simply return the the response from the `HttpClient` call. Since the API returns JSON and you need JSON, no further processing needs to be done.